# Graph Colouring - Eulerian Path

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

I am doing some studying for a test I have in my discrete math class and I have come across this question which I am very stuck on and keep seem to find any help...

If you draw a closed curve in a plane without lifting your pen off of the paper intersecting yourself many times prove that the regions formed by this curve can be coloured with 2 colors.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: **can't find any help**

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291844/2-color-theorem

Comment: This video by Vi Hart touches upon the graph theory behind why you can do that: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=heKK95DAKms

Comment: Hi, @ZubinMukerjee!

Comment: @arbautjc The question was asked and answered before, but the old answer is too terse for me. It's clear enough if the number of self-intersections is **finite**, but surely the general case needs more explanation?

Comment: @bof, I agree with you, the answer there is not enough.

Comment: Yes I agree as well.  I have been pondering this all evening and I still can't get anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know that if a connected graph has all vertices of even degree it is an Eulerian circuit.

Every time you create a vertex you add 2 degrees to either a line (to obtain a vertex of degree 4), or if you are creating the initial vertex you obtain a vertex of degree 1. Every time you add to an existing vertex you increase its degree by 2, except for the last time you enter the initial vertex, where you are increasing its degree by 1. Observe that all vertices in this graph are even.

Thus, note that this is an Eulerian circuit.

We know that Eulerian circuits are planar, so there is a planar representation of this graph.

We know that if a planar graph is Eulerian, its dual is bipartite (and vice versa).

Thus the dual is 2-colourable, which means the original graph's faces are two colourable.

Comment: That makes a lot sense.  Thanks!